# Apache, Web.py and Mod_WSGI Issue - Page Not Found

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi

Please your help to know what is wrong with my configuration Apache + Web.py + Mod_WSGI and my website cannot be loaded, this is my config:

Apache version: 2.7.4

Web.py version -> https://github.com/webpy/webpy

mod_wsgi -> not sure if 3.3 or 3.4

**Directory**
/var/www/pyapps/bot

> web -> link webpy
>   webpy
>   code.py
>   static
>   templates

**Apache**

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combine
```

```
    WSGIScriptAlias /sitea /var/www/pyapps/bot/code.py/

    Alias /sitea/static /var/www/pyapps/bot/static

    Alias /sitea/templates /var/www/pyapps/bot/templates

    AddType text/html .py

    <Directory /var/www/pyapps/bot>

           Order deny,allow

           Allow from All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /sitea/static>
            Options +Indexes
     </Directory>
```

Code.py

import web

urls = (
     '/.*', 'hello',
     )

class hello:
     def GET(self):
         return "Hello, world."

application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()

**Result**

Not Found

The requested URL /sitea was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Port 80

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a trailing slash on the end of the WSGIScriptAlias path:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /sitea /var/www/pyapps/bot/code.py
```

Also note you shouldn't really have your WSGI application files inside the document root (/var/www). Put them somewhere else (and change the WSGIScriptAlias path accordingly).